# El formulario me descarga el archivo datos.php

Tags: php, html, formularios

Tengo un archivo index.html y un archivo datos.php. El archivo index tiene un formulario muy sencillo que se conecta al archivo datos.php. El problema es que al hacer submit en el formulario se me descarga el archivo datos.php.

Este es el archivo index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="datos.php" method="GET">
    <label for="nombre"> Nombre </label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">

    <br>

    <label for="apellido"> Apellido </label>
    <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido">

    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es datos.php

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET["nombre"]) && isset($_GET["apellido"])) {
    echo "Nombre: ".$_GET["nombre"];
    echo "Apellido: ".$_GET["apellido"];
  } else {
    echo "No hay datos";
  }
?>
```

Y esto es lo que sucede cuando hago submit en el formulario
[image: El index.html descarga el archivo php al hacer submit]

**Edito:**

He probado con un navegador diferente pero el problema persiste

**Edito 2:** 
He probado a poner la ruta absoluta en la barra de direcciones pero me aparece el codigo en php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que el método es GET y no POST?

Comment: He probado con los dos métodos. Al principio tenía la recogida de datos en un index.php. Probé a cambiar de archivo y también de método. Pero nada

Comment: No entiendo el problema que planteas. ¿A qué te refieres con que *descarga el archivo `datos.php`*? ¿Los dos archivos están en la misma carpeta?

Comment: Me refiero a que cuando le doy submit me aparece como si quisiera descargar el archivo datos.php Como si fuera una descarga común y corriente

Comment: Sí ya lo vi, es que eso estaba muy a la derecha y no se veía en mi pantalla. Pero, quizá el archivo `datos.php` que hay en el `action` del `form` no es el que nos estás mostrando en la pregunta ¿? Entonces, pregunto de nuevo: ¿ambos archivos están en la misma carpeta? ¿hay más cosas que no nos muestras en `datos.php`? ¿probaste a limpiar la caché o en modo incógnito? Si intenta una descarga es quizá porque está yendo a un archivo `datos.php` que hace eso o que eso estuvo en una versión antigua del código y sigue ejecutándose esa versión.

Comment: Está todo en la misma carpeta. Lo que hay en datos.php es lo que se ve, no hay nada más. También he probado a borrar caché y en modo incognito. Pero nada

Comment: Para descartar eso, puedes probar también en la barra del navegador, poniendo algo así: `http://URLPRINCIPAL/CARPETADONDEESTADATOSPHP/datos.php?nombre=unnombre&apellido=unapellido&otro=rompamoslacache` Esa prueba te ayudará también a ver si es un problema de redirección (observando la URL final en la barra del navegador).

Comment: Ya lo he probado. Ya no lo descarga. Pero me muestra por pantalla todo el código php. He actualizado la pregunta para mostrarlo

Comment: ¿Seguro que tienes instalado el intérprete de php? ¿Otros archivos `.php` funcionan?

Comment: Y, pon otro parámetro **para romper la caché** ¿me explico? Si te muestra el texto del archivo es que no tienes intérprete `.php` o que no está bien referenciado en tu entorno.

Comment: Los demás archivos de php funcionan. Este es el único que me da problemas. Estoy usando xampp y el intérprete está instalado. También acabo de probar con un tercer parámetro y nada

Comment: ¿O sea, tienes otros archivos `.php` en la carpeta `htdocs` que sí funcionan? Crea una copia de `datos.php` y llámalo `nuevo.php` y prueba con ese archivo. Es muy raro  y muy intrigante lo que te ocurre.

Comment: Ya he intentado eso. Al principio lo tenía en index.php que estaba funcionando sin problemas. También probé renombrando. Pero nada

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139578/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-moisesms).

Comment: ¿Has probado con `http://localhost/datos.php`?

Comment: Actúa como si hubiera entrado sin rellenar el formulario. Pero de todas formas se debe poder entrar desde el formulario y no directamente

Answer (score -1):

El código es correcto y funciona, el problema esta en que lo estas ejecutando sobre el navegador directamente como si de un html simple se tratase.

Para poder ejecutar el fichero .php necesitas un servidor web.

Si únicamente quieres ejecutar php, asegurarte de tener php instalado en el equipo, puedes levantar un servidor local con el siguiente comando, estando en el terminal en la carpeta donde tengas los ficheros:

- php -S localhost:8000

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar [answer] y [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.